# LaTeX is not able to process the string in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, latex

Trying to graph a weibull distribution in python3 using the code available at (http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter3/fig_weibull_distribution.html)

```
# Author: Jake VanderPlas
# License: BSD
#   The figure produced by this code is published in the textbook
#   "Statistics, Data Mining, and Machine Learning in Astronomy" (2013)
#   For more information, see http://astroML.github.com
#   To report a bug or issue, use the following forum:
#    https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/astroml-general
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import dweibull
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# This function adjusts matplotlib settings for a uniform feel in the textbook.
# Note that with usetex=True, fonts are rendered with LaTeX.  This may
# result in an error if LaTeX is not installed on your system.  In that case,
# you can set usetex to False.
from astroML.plotting import setup_text_plots
setup_text_plots(fontsize=8, usetex=True)

#------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the distribution parameters to be plotted
k_values = [0.5, 1, 2, 2]
lam_values = [1, 1, 1, 2]
linestyles = ['-', '--', ':', '-.', '--']
mu = 0
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

#------------------------------------------------------------
# plot the distributions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3.75))

for (k, lam, ls) in zip(k_values, lam_values, linestyles):
    dist = dweibull(k, mu, lam)
    plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x), ls=ls, c='black',
             label=r'$k=%.1f,\ \lambda=%i$' % (k, lam))

plt.xlim(0, 5)
plt.ylim(0, 0.6)

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$p(x|k,\lambda)$')
plt.title('Weibull Distribution')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I keet getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX: 



<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x22c11c7a2e8>
```

I cant figure out where is "b'lp'".

Comment: The string `b'lp'` appears if the call to latex does not return anything useful. It's almost impossible to know why that would happen in your case. But of course you first need to verify that you can call latex in your console.

Comment: Of course you simply set `usetex=False` in case you don't want to use latex.

Comment: 'usetex=False' solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: Just note that the comment above that line explicitely says *"In that case, you can set usetex to False."*

Comment: Ran into the same issue but with a different string. Not exactly a code writing fix, but I basically went into MikTex Console (that my tex installation) and ran the cleanup process. I then went into conda prmpt and reinstalled the miktex using `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 miktex`