# matplotlib: Double newline in tick label leads to LaTeX error

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, latex

Dear Stack Overflow community,

This is the first time I raise a Stack Overflow question myself, so I hope I do it right.

I explain my problem using the following code snippet.
My goal is to create two boxplots (`boxplotData`) with corresponding tick marks (`ticks`).
I use LaTeX to typeset the axis labels (`rc('text', usetex=True)`).
Each tick label shall span three lines, where the last line contains the number of data points of the boxplot.
The second line of the first tick mark shall be empty.

In the first tick mark, I want to have an empty line, and this is the problem.

**When I execute the following code, I get the the error `LaTeX was not able to process the following string: b''`.**

**Do you have any ideas how to fix the problem?**

*Code snippet:*

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
import numpy as np

rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True

boxplotData = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]

# !!! Problematic label is ticks[0]
ticks = ["Data 1\n\n(N=%d)" % len(boxplotData[0]), 
         "Data\nwith second line\n(N=%d)" % len(boxplotData[1])]

plt.boxplot(boxplotData, positions=np.array(range(len(boxplotData))), sym='', widths=0.4)

plt.xticks(range(0, len(ticks)), ticks)

plt.show()
```

*Solutions I tried:*

- Add space or \quad between newlines: runs, but the axis label is gone.
- Replace \n\n with LaTeX newline (\\): inserts an empty intermediate line, but now the tick label is no longer centered

The full stacktrace can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/E4enTBRh

Comment: You can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686315/latex-is-not-able-to-process-the-string-in-python. Apparently with `usetex=False` it could work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Joe, I actually wanted to use latex because this produces an output that fits nicely with the rest of my document.

I now chose the following way: (i) I downloaded and installed the Computer Modern font from [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/computer-modern) (ii) I use the following code fragment for switching to non-LaTeX mode:
`params = {'text.usetex' : False,
      'font.size' : 11,
      'font.family' : 'CMU Serif',
      }
plt.rcParams.update(params)`

Comment: You don't have to use `usetex=True` to use TeX-formatted text in matplotlib, except if you want to use any non-standard LaTeX-packages like SIunitx. Instead you can just write your ticks with `$$` notation for equations and just change the general font for matplotlib to your desired output for the rest. This is faster and cleaner.

Comment: @Scotty1, this is a great hint, thanks!

To have serif fonts in `$...$`, I still needed to add `matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'`.

Comment: Note that `\n` is not valid latex. It would be `\newline` instead. Your string needs to be a rawstring also. Centering in latex is not straight forward. Possibly something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163382) would help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, the `\n` appeared to work properly, even though you are right that this is not a valid escape sequence. I also tried `\\` (escaped) as mentioned in the question text. This, however, lead to a disappearing tick label for some strange reason.

Comment: Strange, because `r"\"` is just a whitespace, no newline. Or do you mean `r"\\"`. This would be a new line, but possibly latex cannot determine the width of the text correctly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, sorry, there was  typo in my comment, which I cannot edit anymore. I meant `r"\\"`, as you suggested.